# My regex formula misses one of the items I am trying to match. Is there something I am missing?

Tags: python, regex

I have written this so far and it effectively captures 15 of the 16 students who got a 'B' grade. Unfortunately, the last student with a 'B' is left out. Is there something I am missing?

```
import re
def grades():
    with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
        grades = file.read()
        #grades = re.findall(\w+\s\w+\:\s[B]\s+, grades)
        grades = re.findall("(?P<title>\w+\s\w+)(?=\:\s[B]\s+)",grades)
        print(grades)
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code or sample data as picture(s), instead add the relevant data as (formatted) text to your question.

Comment: Yes, remove `\s+` at the end. Use `\b`. `r'(?P<title>\w+\s\w+)(?=:\sB\b)'` or just ``r'(\w+\s+\w+):\s*B\b'``, or ``r'(?m)^([^:\r\n]+):[^\S\r\n]*B$'``

Comment: Please tell me that you swapped out their actual names with fake names... you didn't just post everyone's real name and their grades on the internet.

Comment: The "Lily Walker" line is not clean. It has " : " instead of ": ". I would clean that up, replace ": " with "," and then save it as a CSV. Now you can open it in Excel or other spreadsheet programs and sort, filter, create pivot tables, etc.

Comment: @JeffC they are not real names. Just part of a practice problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you want to print all the line parts before `:` if the part after `:` is `B`.

So, you can achieve this without a regex:

```py
def grades():
    with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
        grades = []
        for line in file:
            parts = line.strip().split(':')
            if parts[1].strip() == 'B':
                grades.append(parts[0].strip())
        print(grades)
```

You may still get the list with the regex, using

```py
import re
def grades():
    with open ("assets/grades.txt", "r") as file:
        grades = re.findall(r'^([^:\r\n]+):[^\S\r\n]*B$', file.read(), re.M)
        print(grades)
```

where `^([^:\r\n]+):[^\S\r\n]*B$` matches

- `^` - start of a line
- `([^:\r\n]+)` - any zero or more chars other than `:` and CR/LF
- `:` - a colon
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - zero or more horizontal whitespace
- `B` - a `B`
- `$` - end of a line.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ghWoeG/1).

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/13CL8s):

```py
file = """Ronald Mayr: A
Bell Kassulke: B
Alexander Zeller: C
Simon Loidl: B"""

def grades():
    grades = []
    for line in file.splitlines():
        parts = line.strip().split(':')
        if parts[1].strip() == 'B':
            grades.append(parts[0].strip())
    print(grades)

grades()
# => ['Bell Kassulke', 'Simon Loidl']

import re
print( re.findall(r'^([^:\r\n]+):[^\S\r\n]*B$', file, re.M) )
## => ['Bell Kassulke', 'Simon Loidl']
```